# The operation couldn’t be completed. (MKErrorDomain error 4)

Tags: iphone, mkreversegeocoder

I am using the MKReverseGeocoder but I keep getting reverseGeocoder:didFailWithError: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (MKErrorDomain error 4.)". I am passing the geocoder the coordinates of the MKUserLocation annotation. What does this error mean & how can I avoid it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MKErrorDomain error 4 iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926164/mkerrordomain-error-4-iphone)

Answer (score 4):

[My answer to a similar question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926164/mkerrordomain-error-4-iphone/19871031#19871031)

I've met and solved this issue recently. In my case, when Apple Map cannot find any result for a query, it sometimes will just throw this this "MKErrorDomain = 4" error. So I ended up just treating this as "result not found".

It was painstaking to find this out, MapKit needs a better Error handling system.

Answer (score 0):

It's documented at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkerror/code#topics.

If you look into the code of `MKError`, you find the `enum`:

```swift
public enum Code : UInt {

        
        public typealias _ErrorType = MKError

        case unknown = 1

        case serverFailure = 2

        case loadingThrottled = 3

        case placemarkNotFound = 4

        @available(iOS 7.0, *)
        case directionsNotFound = 5

        @available(iOS 13.0, *)
        case decodingFailed = 6
    }
```

So `MKERRORDOMAIN error 4` just means "placemark not found".

Answer (score 0):

Actually this error of
DEBUG:- ERROR The operation couldn’t be completed. (MKErrorDomain error 4.)
I was solved when clear all recentApp's from simulator and re-run it.